# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'VisibleComponent.props')

Tags: react-native

I have got TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'VisibleComponent.props') while running the below code.

Please refer this link to know more about the package
https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view#note

`<SwipeListView
            closeOnRowBeginSwipe
            scrollEnabled={true}
            initialNumToRender={8}
            extraData={this.state}
            refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
            /> }
            useFlatList
            data={this.state.listViewData}
            renderItem={ (rowData, rowMap) =>{
                <SwipeRow 
                  key={rowData.item.key}
                  leftOpenValue={75} 
                  rightOpenValue={-150}
                  closeOnRowPress
                  extraData={this.state}
                  directionalDistanceChangeThreshold={2} >
                    <Hidden data={rowData.item} screen={this.state._screen}/>
                    <FrontFace data={rowData} />
                </SwipeRow>
            }}

          />`

Comment: Please **do not** post images of your code or error. Add it in your question with a proper formatting. This will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the question

Answer (score 1):

try to put a "return" in the renderItem function, like this:

```
        renderItem={ (rowData, rowMap) =>{
           return( <SwipeRow 
              key={rowData.item.key}
              leftOpenValue={75} 
              rightOpenValue={-150}
              closeOnRowPress
              extraData={this.state}
              directionalDistanceChangeThreshold={2} >
                <Hidden data={rowData.item} screen={this.state._screen}/>
                <FrontFace data={rowData} />
            </SwipeRow>);}}
```